# generic map function in Fortran

Tags: fortran, polymorphism

My ultimate goal is to have a generic map function in Fortran i.e. a function that takes an array of an arbitrary type A and a function of type A->B, applies this function to all elements of the given array and returns an array of type B. I couldn't implement this with an array, so I decided to start with just a single element, but even that does not work.

Here's my attempt:

```
program main
  integer :: elem_int
  elem_int = 1
  elem_int = to_int(apply_func(elem_int, add_one_int))
  print *, elem_int

contains
  ! don't know any other way to cast class(*) to int
  function to_int(unbound) result(res) 
    class(*), intent(in) :: unbound
    integer :: res
    select type (unbound)
      type is (integer)
        res = unbound
    end select
  end function

  function apply_func(elem, func) result(new_elem)
    class(*) :: elem
    class(*) :: func
    class(*), allocatable :: new_elem
    ! not sure if this allocation is needed
    allocate(new_elem, source = elem) 
    new_elem = func(elem)
  end function

  function add_one_int(num) result(res)
    integer :: num
    integer :: res
    res = num + 1
  end function
end program
```

This code compiles but crashes with segmentation fault on the line

```
new_elem = func(elem)
```

I thought maybe it thinks that func is an array and tries to index it so I tried defining abstract interface like this:

```
  abstract interface
    function any_func(x)
      class(*) :: x
      class(*), allocatable :: any_func
    end function
  end interface
```

And changed declaration of `func` to `procedure(any_func)`, but then my compiler (ifort 18.0.1) produces the following error:

`error #7069: The characteristics of the associated actual function result differ from the characteristics of the dummy function result.   [ADD_ONE_INT]`

I want an interface such that any 1-arg function conforms to it, but, apparently, this was not the right way to declare it. Any ideas how to make this while thing work? Thanks in advance.

Comment: There is no interface compatible with all functions (for the reason the compiler states).

Comment: There is no easy way to do this in Fortran, because of the lack of “generics”; you will need a specialized interface for each type-kind-rank combination of arguments or nested select-type and select-rank to match all possible patterns. It doesn’t even worth it to be honest, even as an exercise you may brick into the incomplete implementation of those features on the compilers and most probably some ICE. So, good luck

Answer (score 2):

After some digging, I learned that when a function is marked as `elemental` it can be applied to an array, essentially providing the same functionality I have been looking for. Here's an example for a function of `int->real` type

```
program main
  integer :: int_arr(3)
  real :: real_arr(3)
  int_arr = [1, 2, 3]
  real_arr = my_sqrt(int_arr)
  print *, real_arr
contains
  elemental function my_sqrt(arg) result(res)
    integer, intent(in) :: arg
    real :: res
    res = sqrt(real(arg))
  end function
end program
```

Comment: Well, that is a obvious answer. I supposed you were aware of that. Anyway, this is the correct way of doing it.

Answer (score 2):

The upcoming standard Fortran 2018 includes the new construct `select_rank` that will bring more flexibility for coding rank-agnostic procedures, without the constraints of `elemental` procedures. To this day (end of 2018), this standard has been just published officially by ISO, so it may take some time until it gets implemented by vendors.

---

Just for the sake of the trivia, there is a bug in `gfortran 8.2.0` that allows a sort of `map` subroutine to be written in Fortran, using `assumed-rank` dummy argument, and without `select_rank` (or specific routines for each rank).

**Important note:** I DO NOT recommend use of this snippet for production code. I decided to post it just for the appreciation of Fortran fellows that may reach this post, with the hope that it may provide better understanding of the language and maybe inspire some ideas. @DartLenin's [self answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53917337/2938526) is the correct way of doing it in Fortran.

```
module maps
  implicit none

  abstract interface
    integer function unary_int(x)
      integer :: x
    end function
    ! different interfaces would be needed for other arities an types
  end interface

  interface map
    procedure :: map_unary_int  ! + overloads for other implementations 
  end interface

contains
  subroutine map_unary_int(f, x)
    procedure(unary_int) :: f
    integer :: x(..)
    call apply_flatten(x)  ! <- there is the bug: assumed-rank variable shouldn't 
                           ! be allowed as actual argument to assumed-size

  contains
    subroutine apply_flatten(x_)
      integer :: x_(size(x)), i
      x_(1:size(x)) = [(f(x_(i)), i=1, size(x))]
    end
  end
end

program main
  use :: maps
  implicit none

  integer :: int_scl = 0, int_1(1) = 1, int_2x2(2, 2) = 2

  call map(add1, int_scl)
  print *, int_scl, "sh:", shape(int_scl)  ! prints: 1 sh:

  call map(add1, int_1)
  print *, int_1, "sh:", shape(int_1)      ! prints: 2 sh: 1

  call map(add1, int_2x2)
  print *, int_2x2, "sh:", shape(int_2x2)  ! prints: 3 3 3 3 sh: 2 2

contains
  integer function add1(num)
    integer :: num
    add1 = num + 1
  end function
end program
```

Notes:

- It modifies (updates) the passed argument. It cannot be a function because there would be no way to specify the shape of the return value.
- It needs specific implementations for each function arity, and each type and combination of types of its arguments.
- It transforms any procedure into an elemental version of it, without `intent` constraints and lots of rewriting.
- I will report this as a bug to the verdor, so it will probably be fixed soon, and won't work anymore.

Comment: `assumed-rank` is already part of Intel ifort 19, https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/intel-fortran-compiler-190-for-linux-release-notes-for-intel-parallel-studio-xe-2019#new_features